# get active sheet email, and a small problem on my code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two issues on my code, due to my luck of experience in coding, the code that I have is made to copy rows with a specific cell value, in my case it's 'commande confirmer', the first problem that I have is the first line of my values even if it has the specific value it's not copying but on other lines it's working perfectly.
And for the 2nd issue I want to get also when the data copied it transfer with it to the active sheet email, I found how to get it, but how to include it and being transferred I couldn't make it.
Here is my code
and thanks in advance.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15nIAXcP0a14OvvBr5lww4tO23stQD4PEu0QDAcgaFyE/edit?ouid=112360896426304156672&usp=sheets_home&ths=true";
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var pasteSheet = ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

// get source range
var max = copySheet.getMaxRows().toString();
var email= Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
var range = copySheet.getRange(2, 1, max, 10);
var dataValues = range.getValues();

for (i = 1; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    if (dataValues[i][9] === 'COMMANDE CONFIRMER') {
        pasteSheet.appendRow([dataValues[i][0],
            dataValues[i][email],
            dataValues[i][1],
            dataValues[i][2],
            dataValues[i][3],
            dataValues[i][4],
            dataValues[i][5],
            dataValues[i][6],
            dataValues[i][7],
            dataValues[i][8],
            dataValues[i][9]]);

        var clearRow = i + 2;
        copySheet.getRange('A' + clearRow + ':J' + clearRow).clear();
    }
}

// get destination range
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, max, 1);

// clear source values
Browser.msgBox('Commande Confirmer');
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `the first problem that I have is the first line of my values even if it has the specific value it's not copying but on other lines it's working perfectly. And for the 2nd issue I want to get also when the data copied it transfer with it to the active sheet email, I found how to get it, but how to include it and being transferred I couldn't make it.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: my goal is to create a code that copy rows with that have a specific cell value. now the code that i made if the 1st row is having that specific value is not copying that row, but with other rows is working perfectly. also i want to add to this code to copy too the email of the user of the active sheet with this row

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function funko() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15nIAXcP0a14OvvBr5lww4tO23stQD4PEu0QDAcgaFyE/edit?ouid=112360896426304156672&usp=sheets_home&ths=true");
  var psh = ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var range = csh.getRange(2, 1, csh.getLastRow() - 1, 10);
  var cvs = range.getValues();
  let oA = [];
  cvs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[9] == 'COMMANDE CONFIRMER') {
      let t = r.slice();
      t.splice(1, 0, email);
      oA.push(t);
      csh.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, csh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
    }
  });
  psh.getRange(psh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
  Browser.msgBox('Commande Confirmer');
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it gives this error, SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (line 18, file "code.gs"), i tried to  check if there is  a semicolon or something like this but nothing all is good. can't find the problem or it

Comment: Try it again...

Comment: now i receive this error. TypeError: csh.getRange(...).clearContents is not a function (line 15, file "funko")